# Spring Boot - How to disable Keycloak?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot project with keycloak integrated. Now I want to disable keycloak for testing purposes.

I tried by adding `keycloak.enabled=false` to `application.properties` as mentioned in Keycloak [documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter) but it didnt work.

So how do I disable it?

Comment: Do you try just remove keycloak-spring-boot-starter from dependencies 
section of your maven on gradle build file?

Comment: No. I actually wanted to disable it without removing the keycloak dependency.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I want to disable it in Spring Boot controller tests but solutions in this thread didn't work.

Comment: I just posted my solution below. Please have a look.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update 2022**

Please follow this excellent [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-keycloak-security-disable) on Baeldung.

---

For anyone who might have the same trouble, here is what I did.

I didn't disable Keycloak but I made a separate a Keycloak config file for testing purposes.

Here is my config file

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityTestConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.csrf().disable();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public AccessToken accessToken() {
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken();
        accessToken.setSubject("abc");
        accessToken.setName("Tester");

        return accessToken;

    }

}
```

Please note it is important to use this only in a test environment and therefore I have annotated the config as `@Profile("test")`. I have also added an `AccessToken` bean since some of the auditing features in my application depend on it.

Answer (score 5):

It should work, but based on the last comment on the [jira ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4814?_sscc=t) for this, it seems it is not.

As the description state you could exclude the spring boot autoconfiguration for keycloak adding to your `application.properties`: `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfiguration`

Comment: It does not work if you have a also Spring Security enabled, the `enable` flag only works for the Spring Boot Adapter used alone. We have a ticket for supporting also the flag when Spring Secuiryt is used.

Comment: the classname to exclude is now `KeycloakAutoConfiguration` as of spring boot 2.5.6 + Keycloak 16.1.0 (see my answer below)

Answer (score 3):

You need to exclude keycloak auto configuration. In order to do this just add this entry to your related spring configuration file, in your case application.properties.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude = org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 2):

My Workaround:
1. Create a Custom-Filter and add it to the (Spring) Security-Chain in early position.
2. Create a flag in the application.yml (securityEnabled)
3. Query the flag in the Custom-Filter. If 'true' simply go on with the next filter by calling chain.doFilter(). If 'false' create a dummy Keycloak-Account set the roles you need and set it to the context.
4. By the way the roles are also outsourced to the application.yml
5. Skip the rest of the filters in the Security-Chain (so no keycloak-stuff is executed and the corresponding Authorization happend)

In Detail:
1. Class of Custom-Filter

```
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Value("${securityEnabled}")
  private boolean securityEnabled;

  @Value("${grantedRoles}")
  private String[] grantedRoles;

  @Override
  public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
                       FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

      if (!securityEnabled){
          // Read roles from application.yml
          Set<String> roles = Arrays.stream(grantedRoles)
                  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
          // Dummy Keycloak-Account
          RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext session = new RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext(null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
          final KeycloakPrincipal<RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext> principal = new KeycloakPrincipal<>("Dummy_Principal", session);
          final KeycloakAccount account = new SimpleKeycloakAccount(principal, roles, principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext());
          // Dummy Security Context
          SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
          context.setAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationToken(account, false));
          SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

          // Skip the rest of the filters
          req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getServletPath()).forward(req, res);
      }

      chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }
}
```

2. Insert Custom-Filter in the http-Configuration of Spring-Security

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(CustomFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Have a look at the default Filter-Chain after configuring Keycloak:
[Filter-Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkTDW.png)

So it´s obvious to insert the Custom-Filter at position 5 to avoid the whole Keycloak-Magic.

I have used this workaround to defeat the method security and it´s @Secured-Annotation.

Comment: So how do u enable Keycloak again? By commenting out the filter?

Comment: By setting the flag `securityEnabled = true` in the application.yml. Then the if-Statement in the filter is skipped.

Comment: What is the "            .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
"? How do you define the method sessionAuthenticationStrategy()?

Comment: I can't get this approach to work.. my custom filter's "doFilterInternal" method is never invoked, even though the filter itself is registered at the correct place on the chain. Tried with implementing Filter directly or extending GenericFilterBean. "doFilter" is just never called...

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for spring boot 2.5.6 and keycloak 16.1.0

Set this in your application.properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration
```

(The autoconfig class name has changed since earlier answers)

The keycloak adapter dependency brings in the standard spring security autoconfig too, so if you want to disable both use this:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```