# Http401 in tests but working in normal usage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm using keycloak, but for tests I turned it off

```
keycloak.enabled = false
```

In my config I used almost everything to pass test as anonymous

```
public class KeyCloakConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
            http
                    .anonymous().and()  .csrf().disable()    
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/ingredients").permitAll();        

        }

}
```

In test I've got 401 even when with @WithAnonymousUser

```
@WebMvcTest(value = IngredientController.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-development.properties")
class IngredientControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    IngredientService ingredientService;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        reset(ingredientService);
    }

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    void getAllIngredients() throws Exception {
        given(ingredientService.findAll()).willReturn(Arrays.asList(new Ingredient(),new Ingredient()));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/ingredients"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());


    then(ingredientService).should().findAll();
   assertThat(ingredientService.findAll()).hasSize(2);

    }
```

}

What is funny when I use  annotation @WithMockUser in test everything is ok, also  turn on my web service and I go to this url everything is also ok

Also I've got basic authentication beacuse config class is disabled, I'm sure it's basic because in log I can see Using generated security password: 52cce531-b308-4d90-b76f-8984a88879fd. How to add to context slice configuration class ?
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes =  TestSecurityConfig.class) doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This other stackoverflow question may help you out: 
[Spring Boot - How to disable Keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861513/spring-boot-how-to-disable-keycloak).

The solution here is to add

`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfiguration`

to your application-development.properties file

Comment: It's not the case. Keycloak is disabled but with it also I've got basic authentication beacuse config class is disabled. How to add to context slice configuration class ?
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes =  TestSecurityConfig.class) doesn't work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Could you elaborate?