# How to disable Keycloak authentication when running a Spring Boot application with a particular Maven profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, maven-profiles

I have a [minimal Spring Boot based application](https://github.com/dptij/minimal-spring-boot-project). It is meant as a template for developing real applications. That is, people are supposed to clone this project and build real applications on top of it.

When used in production, the endpoints should be protected using Keycloak. During local development, this authentication should be disabled.

To achieve this I created a profile `local-dev` and activated it in [pom.xml](https://github.com/dptij/minimal-spring-boot-project/blob/master/pom.xml):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <profiles>
                    <profile>local-dev</profile>
                </profiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When running with `local-dev` profile, following [security configuration](https://github.com/dptij/minimal-spring-boot-project/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/someproduct/configuration/DevSecurityConfig.java) should apply:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@Profile("local-dev")
public class DevSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.warn("Using configuration Dev Security Conf");

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        http.cors();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public AccessToken accessToken() {
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken();
        accessToken.setSubject("abc");
        accessToken.setName("Tester");

        return accessToken;

    }
}
```

However, if

1. I start the application using `mvn clean spring-boot:run` and
2. open http://localhost:8092/test/ in browser,

I see the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You did not supply enough values to fill path parameters
    at org.keycloak.common.util.KeycloakUriBuilder.buildFromValues(KeycloakUriBuilder.java:577) ~[keycloak-common-11.0.2.jar:11.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.common.util.KeycloakUriBuilder.build(KeycloakUriBuilder.java:571) ~[keycloak-common-11.0.2.jar:11.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.setAuthServerBaseUrl(KeycloakDeployment.java:142) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.2.jar:11.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:139) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.2.jar:11.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.2.jar:11.0.2]
```

This means that Keycloak is not turned off completely.

**How can I make sure that Keycloak is disabled when running the application with the `local-dev` profile?**

Most of the answers to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861513/spring-boot-how-to-disable-keycloak) did not help.

**Update 1:** I changed the code in the following way:

1. Removed

```
autoconfigure:
exclude = org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration
```

from `application-local-dev.yml`.

2. Removed

```
security.basic.enabled: false
management.security.enabled: false
```

from `application-local-dev.yml`.

3. Added

```
keycloak:
enabled: false
```

to `application-local-dev.yml`.

Thereafter the Keycloak-related exception disappeared and the error message in browser changed to

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you 
are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Feb 19 09:59:11 CET 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Comment: Attention: don't confuse Maven Profiles with Spring Profiles. They are 2 different concepts.

Comment: did you figure out how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

What I personally do that I don't include any security or other configurations in the project itself, I just include them during CICD process from either GitLab environment variable or getting them from other path/repo. So in my case all the apps/microservices are running in-non secure mode out of the box to make it easier for developers.