# How to disable Keycloak?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am implementing Keycloak into my Spring Boot application. Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.2</version>
</dependency>
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I created simple configuration class:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class PKeycloakConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test").hasRole("TEST")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to disable Keycloak with `keycloak.enabled = false`. I've seen related questions but none workaround is working for me. Any clues?

Comment: What do you mean by keycloak.enabled=false? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I'd like to completely disable Keycloak using simple propertie flag.

Comment: Do you want to disable it for testing purpose only?

Comment: Have you tried keycloak.enabled = false?

Comment: @Abhijeet Yes, I need an easy way to disable it for testing. I've tried `keycloak.enabled = false` but it's not working for me. I think it's because I am using `spring-boot-starter-security`.

Comment: You can refer answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369181/5790498 by creating different configuration for testing